# Reversing the image colour and background colour

Tags: css, angularjs

I have an image (combination of blue and white in color) and background colour(white) . On click of the div, I need to reverse the colors. (background color to blue) and image(blue part of the image to white colour and white part of the image to blue colour).

**Html :**

```
<div class="col" ng-click="onHomeButtonClick()">
                        <img src="images/iconHome.png" class="menu-icons"><br>
                        </div>
```

**Js code :**

```
this.onHomeButtonClick = function($event){
        $event.target.style.backgroundColor="DarkSlateBlue";
        }
```

**Tried so far :**

Using `$event.target.style.backgroundColor="DarkSlateBlue";` I am just able to set the background colour.But how do i invert the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the CSS deklaration:

This could be like this:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="images/iconHome.png" id="imageToInvert" class="menu-icons">
```

**CSS:**

```
#imageToInvert:hover {
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to use this on click of the div.How do I add to that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that filter:invert(100%) is actually what you're asking for but if it is as indicated in a comment you made, just make a class with that style. Such as  .filterClass{filter: invert(100%)} then add that class in your click event using this element.className +="filterClass";

Comment: I just want to invert the colors of image and bg color. In my case,I have a image which is a combination of white and blue, and a white background.I need to reverse the colors, wherever the colour is blue, I need to change to white, and wherever its white, I need to change it to blue.

Comment: this.onHomeButtonClick = function(){
  
  element.className +="filterClass"; }
I tried this, but it doesnt work . Added the class to CSS as well

Comment: replace "element" with the element you want to add the class too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you [Fiddle](http://%60http://jsfiddle.net/iem_usman/y44j4fjz/%60) this one is for the div with background color you can use the same technique and change the image color too.